# Using traefik as a reverse proxy in front of selenoid

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, selenoid

Im trying to setup a stand-alone server, running [selenoid](https://aerokube.com/selenoid/) with traefik in front, to get both https and basic-auth capabilities.

I'm able to get everything running, but I get this error every time I try to use the browser:
`[SERVICE_STARTUP_FAILED] [wait: http://172.17.0.2:4444 does not respond in 30s]`

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  production_traefik: {}

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge

services:
  selenoid:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/selenoid/Dockerfile
    image: production_selenoid
    container_name: selenoid
    networks:
      - default    
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    command: ["-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json", "-video-output-dir", "/opt/selenoid/video", "-log-output-dir", "/opt/selenoid/logs"]

  selenoid-ui:
    image: "aerokube/selenoid-ui"
    depends_on:
      - selenoid
    links:
      - selenoid
    networks:
      - default    
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: selenoid-ui
    command: ["--selenoid-uri", "http://selenoid:4444"]

  selenoid-chrome:
    image: "selenoid/chrome:latest"
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: selenoid-chrome
    networks:
      - default 


  traefik:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/traefik/Dockerfile
    image: production_traefik
    container_name: traefik
    networks:
      - default    
    depends_on:
      - selenoid-ui
      - selenoid
    volumes:
      - production_traefik:/etc/traefik/acme:z
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
      - "0.0.0.0:443:443"
      - "0.0.0.0:4444:4444"
```

My traefik.yml:

```
log:
  level: INFO

entryPoints:
  web:
    # http
    address: ":80"
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: web-secure

  web-secure:
    # https
    address: ":443"

  hub:
    address: ":4444"

certificatesResolvers:
  letsencrypt:
    acme:
      email: "my@email.com"
      storage: /etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: web

http:
  routers:
    web-secure-router:
      rule: "Host(`selenoid.mydomain.com`)"
      entryPoints:
        - web-secure
      service: ui
      middlewares:
        - basic-test-auth
      tls:
        certResolver: letsencrypt

    hub-secure-router:
      rule: "Host(`selenoid.mydomain.com`)"
      entryPoints:
        - hub
      service: hub
      middlewares:
        - basic-test-auth
      tls:
        certResolver: letsencrypt

  middlewares:
    basic-test-auth:
      basicAuth:
        users:
          - "test-user:$apr1$n1gqpoi0$nspcnDDaBpJiTCoT2WaSw1"

  services:
    ui:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://selenoid-ui:8080

    hub:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://selenoid:4444

providers:
  file:
    filename: /etc/traefik/traefik.yml
    watch: true
```

Traefik Dockerfile:

```
FROM traefik:v2.2.11
RUN mkdir -p /etc/traefik/acme \
  && touch /etc/traefik/acme/acme.json \
  && chmod 600 /etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
COPY ./compose/traefik/traefik.yml /etc/traefik
```

selenoid Dockerfile:

```
FROM aerokube/selenoid:latest-release
RUN mkdir -p /etc/selenoid
COPY ./compose/selenoid/browsers.json /etc/selenoid
```

browser.json:

```
{
    "chrome": {
        "default": "latest",
        "versions": {
            "latest": {
                "image": "selenoid/chrome",
                "port": "4444",
                "tmpfs": {"/tmp":"size=512m"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the log:

```
[INIT] [Loading configuration files...]
[INIT] [Loaded configuration from /etc/selenoid/browsers.json]
[INIT] [Video Dir: /opt/selenoid/video]
[INIT] [Logs Dir: /opt/selenoid/logs]
[INIT] [Your Docker API version is 1.41]
[INIT] [Listening on :4444]
[NEW_REQUEST] [test-user] [*.*.*.*, 172.19.0.5]
[NEW_REQUEST_ACCEPTED] [test-user] [*.*.*.*, 172.19.0.5]
[LOCATING_SERVICE] [chrome] [latest]
[USING_DOCKER] [chrome] [latest]
[CREATING_CONTAINER] [selenoid/chrome]
[STARTING_CONTAINER] [selenoid/chrome] [f5331d61628342d5900b7929f350af67a2457f8ba6e2f7c9c209227cc6e30a9c]
[CONTAINER_STARTED] [selenoid/chrome] [f5331d61628342d5900b7929f350af67a2457f8ba6e2f7c9c209227cc6e30a9c] [0.35s]
[REMOVING_CONTAINER] [f5331d61628342d5900b7929f350af67a2457f8ba6e2f7c9c209227cc6e30a9c]
[CONTAINER_REMOVED] [f5331d61628342d5900b7929f350af67a2457f8ba6e2f7c9c209227cc6e30a9c]
[SERVICE_STARTUP_FAILED] [wait: http://172.17.0.2:4444 does not respond in 30s]
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure `-container-network` flag of Selenoid is set to the name of the Docker network where Selenoid is running.

Comment: Ah, missed the option in the documentation. Thanks, and thank you for the great project!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon the same problem:

```
networks:
  selenoidweb:
    name: selenoidweb
    driver: bridge
```

And use this command for your selenoid service:

```
command: ["-container-network", "selenoidweb", "-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json", "-video-output-dir", "/opt/selenoid/video", "-log-output-dir", "/opt/selenoid/logs"]
```